# Adding Parameters to Spring Security Logout

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

Hai can I add parameters to Spring Security Logout. I have configured logout request in security.xml as below.

`<sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logoutsuccess.do" logout-url="/logout.do" />`

while Login, after successful login, I am validating various aspects of user account on Custom Success Handler to validate the Account Subscription Status, Approve/DisApprove etc and based on it will send Logout request if any of the condition fails. I would like to display custom error message on logout page and so would like to send that parameter along with logout request.

Answer (score 2):

Write a custom logout handler. Put attribute [success-handler-ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-logout-attributes) in xml configuration file.

e.g

```
<sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logoutsuccess.do" 
  logout-url="/logout.do" 
  success-handler-ref="YourCustomLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
```

Then extend the [SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler.html) or implement the [LogoutHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler.html).

e.g

```
public class YourCustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {  

    @Override  
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,  
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {  

        //Do what you want to do here
        //....... 

        //below does the 'standard' spring logout handling  
        super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);         
    }  
}
```

An alternate way of doing this is shown [here](http://cyriltech.blogspot.com/2013/02/spring-logout-filter.html). This also shows how to redirect to a particular url and manually handle session management.